# Closing nested tabs using WPF?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, tabs, nested

I'm trying to design a UI that contains nested tabs, but I can't seem to find information on how to remove the nested tabs in an MVVM fashion.

Here's my XAML (snipped for brevity):

```
<TabControl Name="ProjectTabControl" DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectTabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding FileTabs}" Padding="1">
            <Button Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}" CommandParameter="TabItem" />
         </TabControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

My question is: what argument(s?) should I be passing in CommandParameter, and how would I affect it in the ViewModel to properly remove the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have a solid understanding of how to implement an M-V-VM pattern in WPF. It looks like you know understand DataBinding but the pattern your sample demonstrates seems to be missing an understand of ViewModels and Commands, which are really required for MVVM.

Review the article linked below and the sample application it uses. You should find what you're looking to do is demonstrated here and is pretty easy to implement.

[The Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Design Pattern for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

I hope that this doesn't seem like a cop-out but it would require a significant amount of re-posting of the linked article to get you where you want to go.  Go read the article, work through the sample and if you still have problems, post on this question and I'll make sure to watch for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll admit--I am very new to all of this.

I've read the article you linked a few times, but it's a bit intimidating for someone new to most of the concepts.

I found this one, which's been very helpful at translating Josh Smith's work into layman's terms: http://codingtales.com/2010/02/06/Creating-a-Complete-Tabbed-Interface-in-WPF-using-MVVM/.

Comment: I think the concept that's confusing me most is the proper way for the View to communicate information to the ViewModel. I've been using CommandParameter, but that doesn't seem to be the correct application. The above article seems to indicate it's done by listening to OnPropertyChanged, but I can't seem to figure out how to use OnPropertyChanged in MVVM Light. Sorry, as I said, I'm completely new to this whole process.

Comment: Sorry for comment spam. OK, I got my code working using the article I mentioned, setting up an event handler, a proper command binding, and a variable to relay the selected tab index. My question now is: is the proper way to set this up for nested tabs to have an event handler in each workspace (one in ProjectTabs and another in FileTabs handling the collections separately), or is the correct method to have on event handler that handles calls from both sets of tabs? Sorry, I'm kinda lost.

Comment: The way that I would approach your problem would be to have a ViewModel for each tab. I would then have each tab, just like Josh's sample project, have a command hooked up to the button that you're going to have the user click to close the tab. That command, within the appropriate ViewModel, will do the right things. (Remove tab from a collection for example.) This way also, you don't have to pass a parameter stating which tab to close. The user just clicks the right button and that button is correctly hooked up to the right ViewModel. I'll try and mock up a quick sample for you.

Comment: OK, so basically, I would create my projects workspace, then within that I'd set up the close tab command and hook it into that workspaces events, etc., then I'd create my files workspace and within that I'd set up the close tab command for files? And if I wanted to do that without having lots of duplicated code, I'd set up a general workspace class derived from ViewModelBase that I'd derive my project and files workspaces from? (And when I say "close tab command," what I really mean is the command to remove elements from the collection...)

Comment: `(And when I say "close tab command," what I really mean is the command to remove elements from the collection...)` This is correct!! This is exactly one of the points I was trying to convey.

Comment: I have a working sample that I think demonstrates what you'd like to do. The sample is probably too big to post up here. If you email me at davew at quadrus dot com I'll send you the VS 2010 solution.