# Silverlight MVVM: MainView w/ SubViews OR MainViewModel w/SubViewModels

Tags: silverlight, architecture, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a MainView with a Tabbed UI.

How do I add a new TabItem (= View) to the TabControl?
Basicaly I see 2 ways:

1.)
    * from code in the MainView I can add a new tab.
    * the new tab contains a view with a referece to it's viewmodel.

2.)
    * from code in the MainViewModel I can add a new viewmodel to a List of childViewModels
    * the tabcontrol of the mainView is bound to that list

I prefere case #1 somehow, cause I think the view should know and instanciate it's VM (maybe by using the MVVM light ViewModelLocator) and not the other way round.
But how can I refere from the newly created VM to the MainVM? For example: the MainVM has a property 'IsAdmin'; how can I access (bind) that property from the SubViewModel?

alternative #2: how does the TabControl know, which view should be "rendered" for different ViewModels? How can I "map" from the SubViewModels to the corresponding "SubViews"?

Thanks for sharing your ideas!

Comment: what is the nature of the views? (are they the same), and how are they added?

Comment: The views can be very different. Like visualization of entities (products, customers) but also previews of documents, etc.  
Currently I add them from a codebehind method of the surrounding MainView and let the TabControl itself do the handling of closing and removing tabs, which works quite well.  
But I do believe, that this isn't the best approach and the "Tab-Controlling" should go somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would [check out this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023624/closing-nested-tabs-using-wpf/5023871#5023871) as the answer can be applied to helping you with your problem.

In the spirit of MVVM, you will want to follow alternative #2. Let your ViewModel logic help you determine which "tabs" you need to display and use DataTemplates to represent those objects. Then you will get them bound to the DataContext of the View and your binding in the DataTemplate (View) will work correctly.

Comment: Maybe the "implicit DataTemplates" of Silverlight 5 will be a good solution for that? Having a collection of ViewModels. Bind it to the TabControl. And let Silverlight 5 decide, how it should be rendered by using an implicit DataTemplate for each ViewModel. So the "controlling" part will come out-of-the-box with SL5.

Comment: WPF already has the ability to associate a DataTemplate with a ViewModel such that when WPF encounters a ViewModel in a binding, it will find the appropriate view for rendering that ViewModel. You can achieve the same thing in Silverlight with DataTemplateSelector Converter on a binding. It's a bit clunky compared to WPF but still doable.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas,

MVVM really is MVVMC. I would advise having a controller for the MainView which contains a method for creating a new tab. If the TabControl is complicated, you might put the functionality in the TabControl itself.

Separation of concerns (MODEL versus VIEWMODEL versus VIEW versus CONTROLLER) is compromised when actuation functionality is located in the models. (M or VM).

Regards,

Guido

Comment: Good point! In fact, I do have this kind of "Controller" but currently it is located directly in the codebehind of the MainView. I can refactor that easily. BUT... that's in contrast to Dave Whites advice (see below). I also get more and more the feeling, that the "controlling part" should be more tied to the MainViewModel instead to the MainView. Hmmm...

Comment: The MVVM pattern is more closely related to the MVP pattern. Often, MVVM is described as a specialized WPF version of MVP.  In MVVM, the ViewModel is considered to act in a controller-ish manner. I haven't seen an actual Controller class in an MVVM implementation yet.

Comment: @Dave: Interesting. I tend to think of MVP as a 'dialect' of MVC. I would love to show you the source code for a very data rich WPF client I architected that has the controllers in a MVVMC pattern running the show. Unfortunately it is propitiatory. :(